# Empty a file while in use in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to empty a file in linux while in use, it's a log file so it is continuosly written.
Right now I've used:

```
echo -n > filename
```

or

```
cat /dev/null > filename
```

but all of this produce an empty file with a newline character (or strange character that I can see as ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^.. on `vi`) and I have to remove manually with `vi` and `dd` the first line and then save.

If I don't use `vi` adn `dd` I'm not able to manipulate file with `grep` but I need an automatic procedure that i can write in a shell script.

Ideas?

Comment: Why do you write `@@@@` when you actually see `^@^@^@^@`?

Comment: Finally I've solved using a logrotate callback via webserver

Comment: This is wrong, `echo -n` nor `cat /dev/null` are inserting any newline to your file.

Answer (score 25):

This should be enough to empty a file:

```
> file
```

However, the other methods you said you tried should also work. If you're seeing weird characters, then they are being written to the file by something else - most probably whatever process is logging there.

Answer (score 22):

What's going on is fairly simple: you *are* emptying out the file.

Why is it full of `^@`s, then, you ask?  Well, in a very real sense, it is not.  It does not contain those weird characters.  It has a "hole".

The program that is writing to the file is writing a file that was opened with `O_WRONLY` (or perhaps `O_RDWR`) but *not* `O_APPEND`.  This program has written, say, 65536 bytes into the file at the point when you empty out the file with `cp /dev/null filename` or `: > filename` or some similar command.

Now the program goes to `write` another chunk of data (say, 4096 or 8192 bytes).  Where will that data be written?  The answer is: "at the current seek offset on the underlying file descriptor".  If the program used `O_APPEND` the `write` would be, in effect, preceded by an `lseek` call that did a "seek to current end-of-file, i.e., current length of file".  When you truncate the file that "current end of file" would become zero (the file becoming empty) so the seek would move the `write` offset to position 0 and the write would go there.  But the program did not use `O_APPEND`, so there is no pre-`write` "reposition" operation, and the data bytes are written at the current offset (which, again, we've claimed to be 65536 above).

You now have a file that *has no data* in byte offsets 0 through 65535 inclusive, followed by some data in byte offsets 65536 through 73727 (assuming the `write` writes 8192 bytes).  That "missing" data is the "hole" in the file.  When some other program goes to read the file, the OS pretends there *is* data there: all-zero-byte data.

If the program doing the `write` operations does not do them on block boundaries, the OS will in fact allocate some extra data (to fit the write into whole blocks) and zero it out.  Those zero bytes are not part of the "hole" (they're real zero bytes in the file) but to ordinary programs that do not peek behind the curtain at the Wizard of Oz, the "hole" zero-bytes and the "non-hole" zero bytes are indistinguishable.

What you need to do is to modify the program to use `O_APPEND`, or to use library routines like `syslog` that know how to cooperate with log-rotation operations, or perhaps both.

[Edit to add: not sure why this suddenly showed up on the front page and I answered a question from 2011...]

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer, as it's the most complete and correct here!

Answer (score 7):

Another way is the following:

```
cp /dev/null the_file
```

The advantage of this technique is that it is a single command, so in case it needs sudo access only one sudo call is required.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just `:>filename`?

(`:` is a bash builtin having the same effect as `/bin/true`, and both commands don't echo anything)

Proof that it works:

```
fg@erwin ~ $ du t.txt
4       t.txt
fg@erwin ~ $ :>t.txt
fg@erwin ~ $ du t.txt
0       t.txt
```

Comment: `:` is not an alias for `/bin/true`. In bash at least, it's a null command - it doesn't nothing. It does always return true, however. It's also actually unnecessary here - you can just do `> file`.

Comment: @pgl yes, in bash it is a builtin, I really meant that it could be a replacement for `/bin/true`. Rephrasing...

Comment: same behaviour. First time the process write on a file it writes @@@@@@@ char

Comment: @MiroBarsocchi then it means the program `seek()`s before it writes, it doesn't actually fill the file (the `@` you see are zeroes btw).

Comment: @fge What do you mean with "the ^@ you see are zeroes" ? I don't know exactly when this is written so sometimes with just ':>filename it' works, sometimes I have the ^@. Basically when I have the ^@ I can not use GREP on file

Answer (score 3):

If it's a log file then the proper way to do this is to use logrotate. As you mentioned doing it manually does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have not a linux shell here to try ir, but have you try this?

```
echo "" > file
```

Comment: yes, same behaviour as echo -n > filename but with a newline. Anyway same strange char at the begin of a file